# Catch exception with python under windows and UNIX

Tags: python, exception

I got some code that i did 3 years ago under python 2.5 or so.  It was working properly back then  It was something like this :

```
try:
   if os.path.exists(os.path.join(TRACES.log_file_path, TRACES.log_file_name)):
      os.remove(os.path.join(TRACES.log_file_path, TRACES.log_file_name))
except IOError , e:
   print (str(e))
```

Now, under 3.2, this piece of code is not working for windows.  I get the following error : Invalid syntax

To resolve the problem, i changed the "," for "as" to have the following :

```
try:
  if os.path.exists(os.path.join(TRACES.log_file_path, TRACES.log_file_name)):
    os.remove(os.path.join(TRACES.log_file_path, TRACES.log_file_name))
except IOError as e:
  print (str(e))
```

I was happy, but couple minutes later, i realized that the code was not working into a cygwin prompt, the compiler didn't like the "as", i had to switch back to a comma!

I would like to know what is the exact syntax of try except?  I would like to have the same syntax for windows, unix and mac os

Thank you

Comment: Uh, and you're also using Python 3.2 under cygwin/Unix/MacOs? Just checking...

Comment: You can't run the same scripts with Python 3 and Python 2.5. You shouldn't even be trying to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system shouldn't make a difference to Python syntax. Most likely, your cygwin installation includes a Python 2.5. (Confirm this by just typing 'python' in your cygwin prompt and checking the banner.)

Note that 'a cygwin prompt' is not Unix.

If you must, install Python 3 under Cygwin.

Comment: @RusselBorogove  Gotcha... i though that installing python 3.0 on the server would make it available thru the cygwin shell.. that is not the case!  Thank you